# In layoutSubviews cell bounds or frame should be set?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, layoutsubviews

I am afraid to set cell's `frame` in `layoutSubviews`, because I know I want to place cell into 0 `origin.x` position, but I am not sure about `origin.y` position. But sometimes set only the `bounds` so the `size` of the cell, has strange effect, i.e. cell 'moves out' from `collectionView`.

What do you set frame or bunds in layoutSubviews?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure that setting frame manually is good idea for `UICollectionViewCell`/`UITableViewCell` subclasses. I believe such approach can influence private behavior of `UICollectionView`/`UITableView` and break their usual layout.

I think it should be implemented in use datasource and delegate methods only (+ `UICollectionViewLayout`). Sometimes you can change superview frame to get the expected effect.